# How to remove libgcc_s.so dependencies from uclibc

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot

My understanding is that libgcc shouldn't be used in embedded systems and uclibc need to be used wherever possible. During buildroot build it is seen that it is generating libgcc as well. If I have to remove libgcc dependency completely (no static as well as shared) and only rely on uclibc, is it possible ? Is there any configuration which can effect this change ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing `glibc` with `libgcc`. The latter contains helper functions for your architecture (e.g. integer division on ARM Application Profile) and *not* the standard C library functions. These functions may be part of the "run-time ABI" and might be required *regardless* of the C library you are using (even when compiling for bare-metal).

The uClibc is a drop-in replacement for `glibc`, not for `libgcc`.